# How to conditionally initialization a class  via spring

Tags: java, spring, initialization

How to conditionally  initialization a class  via spring?
If some condtion is true then i want one argument to be passed else some other 
argument

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="Factory">

  if something then
   <constructor-arg>
      <util:map>
        <!-- configure your map here, or reference it as a separate bean -->
        <entry key="java.lang.String" value="key">....</entry>
      </util:map>
   </constructor-arg>
  else
    <constructor-arg>
      <util:map>
        <!-- configure your map here, or reference it as a separate bean -->
        <entry key="java.lang.String" value="key">....</entry>
      </util:map>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Expression Language might do the trick for you. [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Comment: You should provide an example if you feel you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly the way that you have specified. Define a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) this way, say for eg. For generating a Customer Bean:

```
public class CustomFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Customer>{

    private int customProperty;

    public int getCustomProperty() {
        return customProperty;
    }

    public void setCustomProperty(int customProperty) {
        this.customProperty = customProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer getObject() throws Exception {
        if (customProperty==1)
            return new Customer("1", "One");        
        return new Customer("999", "Generic");
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Customer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

That is basically it, now based on how you inject in th properties of the factory bean, the actual bean instantiation can be controlled in the `getObject` method above